# switch case isset triggered when case is -not- set

Tags: php, get, switch-statement

--Let me add this. This code works for me the way it is. I just do not know why it works.--

I can't figure this out.

```
switch ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
case isset($_GET['test0']):
    echo "test0<br>";
    break;
case isset($_GET['test1']):
    echo "test1<br>";
    break;
case isset($_GET['test2']):
    echo "test2<br>";
    break;
case isset($_GET['test3']):
    echo "test3<br>";
    break;
case isset($_GET['test4']):
    echo "test4<br>";
    break;
default:
    echo "no test<br>";
    break;
}
```

When the url is index.php?test0, "test0" is shown.

When the url is index.php?test4, "test4" is shown.

When the url is index.php?test999, "no test" is shown.

When the url is index.php?tes, "no test" is shown.

When the url is index.php?, or index.php, "test0" is shown.

Why is this? The condition is not met, so should the default not be shown?

Comment: What are you trying to do? if `index.php?test0` is the url? then, what do you what the `switch` to echo out? ... am just trying to understand your question

Comment: well, it does what i need it to do. if i use ?test3, it echos test3. if the ?condition is wrong, it echos the default. i just dont know what it triggers the first case when no ?condition is in the url.

Comment: I tried my code, and it works. Might be a bit radical though

Answer (score 2):

`switch` can't be used this way. `isset()` returns true or false, not something (a string, an int, etc) you can match against. What you are basically doing is:

```
switch ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    case true:
        echo "test0<br>";
        break;
    case true:
        echo "test1<br>";
        break;
    case false:
        echo "test2<br>";
        break;
    case false:
        echo "test3<br>";
        break;
    case true:
        echo "test4<br>";
        break;
    default:
        echo "no test<br>";
        break;
}
```

`case`s are considered from top to bottom. In this case, $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] is automatically type-converted to bool (which will return true in this case). The first case it sees would be test0, so it echos that. If you do that for test0-4, it will give you the false illusion that this code is working as intended, while it's not considering the edge cases.

The only way you can achieve what you want is by using multiple ifs, or by redesigning your application.

Comment: but it does work. if the url is ?test1, ?test3, etc. it works. and if ?notacase is used, the default kicks in. i'm just wondering how the first case is used if no ?condition is used.

Comment: @JSP254 It actually shouldn't match to anything and jump straight to default for any test cases you mentioned, because you matched a string to cases of true/false.

Comment: i see your point @Timothy. i guess it triggers the correct condition as true, and echos appropriately. and with the condition is wrong or false, it triggers the default. but i still cant figure out why no condition in the url triggers the first case. i'm stumped.

Comment: Look at the data ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) and do a manual check.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Rich men's way would be use a PHP IDE and set a breakpoint at switch ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']). The poor men's way would be to die(var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])) and check the results.

Comment: i placed die(var_dump($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])); after the switch. it resulted in:
test0
string '' (length=0)
using the url of index.php?

Comment: @JSP254 I've clarified more in the original answer.

Comment: i dont know bro. it is actually working. it's not popping up any errors, and it produces the intended result. maybe it's not supposed to work, but it does.

Comment: @JSP254 It's giving you a false illustration that it "works", while it fails for edge cases. As you handle untrusted inputs (this is one of them), you *must* consider the edge cases (e.g when user types in something you did _not_ intend, like index.php?thispageisboring) or else your code will silently fail or give you this false illusion. This is especially important if you handle the database as well - if you don't make sure the input is what you intended, malicious users can drop your database by making use of this vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

> When the url is index.php?, or index.php, "test0" is shown.
>
> Why is this? The condition is not met, so should the default not be shown?

Like a good question, your question as well contains the answer already.

You already have realized that the condition must be met even you think it is not met. Therefore you ask. So let's see *which* condition is met:

```
case isset($_GET['test0']):
    echo "test0<br>";
    break;
```

This is a test for `isset($_GET['test0'])` and we know with the request that this is `FALSE`. So this test tests for `FALSE`.

Now let's see against what this tests:

```
switch ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
```

That is `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. So if `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`  is `FALSE` the `test0` will be output.

Because `switch { case:}` in PHP does loose comparison, the empty string `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is `FALSE`. This is why you see the output.

Easy if you know why, right? And all so logical.

And what you wanted to test against was not `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but just `TRUE`:

```
switch (TRUE)
{
    case isset($_GET['test0']) :
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
$found = false;
for($i=0;$i <=4; $i++){
    if( isset($_GET['test'.$i]) ){
        echo "test".$i;
        $found = true;
    }
}

if(!$found){
    echo "no test";
}
```

Comment: ummm. not sure bro. the original code does what i need it to do. just trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

This gets the job done, too.

```
<?php 

$q = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

    if(!empty($q) && isset($q) && strlen($q) >0 ){
        $url = $q;

        switch ($url){
           case true;
             echo $url;
             break;
            }
        }

    else {
    echo "no test<br>";
    }
```